# Large configuration cache synchronisation

Tags: distributed

A platform has all it's configuration data in a central MySQL database.

For processes running in the platform, this configuration is read in-memory in a  cache comprising objects with elaborate data-structures - suited for the purpose for running a real-time platform.

I need help with periodic distribution of this central cache to each of the distributed components. Currently, the application processes need to pause their regular tasks while the cache synchronisation is in-progress, where cache-synchronisation refers to clearing the old in-memory cache and re-creating them from the new data in MySQL.

One option I can think of, is to have the processes work off the old cache while a copy of the cache is being generated, then switch from old to new and delete the old one. But the cache is really quite huge and expected to grow.

Is there a better alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What is the bottleneck? RAM? Network? Time it is requrired to convert data into internal representation?

Anyway, here is number of additional options:

1. If consistency constraints allow, then split configuration into chunks and update these chunks one by one. This will prevent going out of memory. (Node downloads chunk #0, converts it to internal application format and deletes previous version of chunk #0; next it moves on to chunk #1; and so on).
2. Depending on language/platform you are using, it may be possible to create standalone tool that would convert configuration into internal application format, rather than doing this on each of nodes separately. For example, if you need to binary search in huge list of sorted numbers, conversion tool may load all values from mysql, sort them and write into file. Next, this file is copied to each of nodes, and each of nodes loads this file replacing previous version. Nodes still would pause for a moment, but you won't loose time on conversion.
3. Update nodes one by one (once again, if consistency requirements allow doing this): remove node #0 from cluster, drop old version of configuration on it, load new version; add back into cluster; move to next node.
4. Simply, add more RAM.